# Diferencia entre Fragment y FragmentActivity

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragment

Bueno, el título es bastante claro, ¿Cuál es la diferencia entre Fragment y FragmentActivity?

Me gustaría saberlo para saber cual es la mejor opción para el siguiente caso:
Tengo dos fragmentos y en una actividad principal(con un NavigationView) en la cual se va a cargar un fragmento u otro(los dos a la vez por ahora no).

También he pensado en utilizar un ViewPager para gestionar los fragmentos, que se utiliza de una manera bastante sencilla y me guarda los datos si giro la pantalla y no tengo que estar controlándolo yo, pero el problema de ese es que me carga los dos fragmentos al inicio de la actividad (o eso creo) y ademas permite cambiar los fragmentos al deslizar el dedo a un lado y a otro.

Comment: Agregare descripciones breves y con imagenes para explicar la diferencia la cual es sencilla simplemente FragmentActivity tiene soporte para usar Fragments, pero lo explicaré...

Answer (score 12, accepted):

[**Fragment**](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html) como una [Activity](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html) contiene su propio Ciclo de vida y representa un comportamiento o una parte de la interfaz de usuario en una [Activity](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html), lo más importante es que puede ser agregada o removida de la Activity que la contiene, esta adjunta siempre a una [Activity](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html) la cual requiere para trabajar.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[**FragmentActivity**](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/FragmentActivity.html) es una [Activity](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html) que contiene soporte para Fragments, por lo cual nos da la posibilidad de realizar dentro de ella transacciones de Fragments, es decir agregar o eliminar.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

#### La principal diferencia entre [**FragmentActivity**](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/FragmentActivity.html) y [Fragment](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html) es que el  [Fragment](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html) es un componente que representa un comportamiento o una parte de la interfaz de usuario en una [Activity](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html), pero necesita una [Activity](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html) en la cual mostrarse; y el [**FragmentActivity**](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/FragmentActivity.html) es una [Activity](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html) como la conocemos pero que contiene soporte para Fragmentos por lo cual podemos agregar un Fragment a esta.

---

Esta sería la diferencia entre el ciclo de vida de un [`Activity`](http://[Activity][2]) y un [`Fragment`](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html):

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

---

Existe una respuesta en el sitio SO en inglés, repondida por [@MrK](https://stackoverflow.com/users/898375/mrk) que hace referencia a tu pregunta: **"Diferencia entre Fragment y FragmentActivity"**

Un **Fragmento** es una sección de una Actividad, que tiene:

- Su propio ciclo de vida
- Recibe sus propios eventos de entrada
- Se puede agregar o quitar mientras se está ejecutando la actividad.
- Un Fragmento debe estar siempre incrustado en una Actividad.

Los fragmentos no forman parte de la API antes de HoneyComb (Android 3.0). Si desea utilizar Fragmentos en una aplicación orientada a una versión de plataforma anterior a HoneyComb, debe agregar el paquete de soporte a su proyecto y utilizar **FragmentActivity** para almacenar sus fragmentos.

La clase `FragmentActivity` tiene una API para tratar con fragmentos, mientras que la clase [Activity](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html) antes de Android 3.0 no la contenia.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/10609839/250260

Comment: Excelente... 

Comment: Excelente respuesta, encima le añadiste al final una parte muy buena de la respuesta de EO inglés y se quedó perfecta ^^. Muchas gracias, dudas totalmente resueltas.

Comment: Muchas gracias companeros! (づ◔ ͜ʖ◔)づ

Comment: La respuesta mas completa, saludos

Answer (score 3):

Al parecer hay una diferencia a nivel de conceptos pero no de funcionalidad. `FragmentActivity` es trabajado en versiones anteriores en Android, cuando utilizas `android.app.Fragment` y para que no se generen excepciones de compatibilidad, se usa `FragmentActivity`, mientras que si utilizas `android.support.v4.app.Fragment` corresponde ocupar `Fragment`, ambas son identicas, tienen las mismas funciones aunque cambian un poco de nombre, en `FragmentActivity` la funcion `getLoaderManager()` y `getFragmentManager()` cambian a `getSupportLoaderManager()` y `getSupportFragmentManager()` respectivamente. Pero ambas siguen siendo una `subclase` de `Activity`

Comment: Realmente no sé realmente si las llamaría "subclases" de Activity. FragmentActivity diría más que es un tipo de Activity más que una subclase. Y Fragment sería como una sección de una Actividad.

Answer (score 2):

Un `FragmentActivity` es una `Activity` que puede soportar `Fragments`.

Sin embargo un `Fragment` por sí solo siempre tiene que depender de una `Activity`. Se podría decir que es cómo una sección de la `Activity`.

Answer (score 2):

He encontrado una pregunta similar en el foro de StackOverflow en inglés [repondida](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10609839/3683321) por @MrK que creo que está muy bien explicada y tiene bastantes votos positivos, por lo que me he decicido a traducirla ya que se amolda a lo que tu preguntas.

### Traducción:

Un [`Fragment`](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals/fragments.html) es una sección de un `Activity`, que tiene:

- Su propio ciclo de vida
- Recibe sus propios eventos de entrada
- Puede añadirse o eliminarse mientras se ejecuta `Activity`.

Un `Fragment` siempre debe estar incrustado en una`Activity`.

`Fragments` no forman parte de la API antes de HoneyComb (3.0). Si quieres usar `Fragments` en una aplicación dirigida a una versión de plataforma antes de HoneyComb, debes añadir el [Paquete de soporte](http://developer.android.com/sdk/compatibility-library.html) a tu proyecto y utilizar [`FragmentActivity`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/FragmentActivity.html) para guardar tus `Fragments`. La clase `FragmentActivity` tiene una API para tratar con `Fragments`, mientras que la clase `Activity`, antes de HoneyComb, no.

Si tu proyecto está dirigido a HoneyComb o más reciente solamente, debes usar `Activity` y no `FragmentActivity` para incrustar tus `Fragments`.

Algunos detalles:

Utiliza `android.app.Fragment` con `Activity`. Utiliza `android.support.v4.app.Fragment` con `FragmentActivity`. No agregues el paquete de soporte `Fragment` a`Activity`, ya que provocará que se lance una excepción.

Una cosa a tener cuidado con: `FragmentManager` y `LoaderManager` tienen versiones de soporte independientes para FragmentActivity:

Si estás usando un `Fragment` en una `Activity` (HoneyComb y arriba), llama a:

- `getFragmentManager()` para obtener `android.app.FragmentManager`
- `getLoaderManager()` para obtener `android.app.LoaderManager`

Si estás usando un `Fragment` en un `FragmentActivity` (pre-HoneyComb), llama a:

- `getSupportFragmentManager()` para obtener `android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager`.
- `getSupportLoaderManager()` para obtener `android.support.v4.app.LoaderManager`

Por lo tanto,  **no** hacer

```
//don't do this
myFragmentActivity.getLoaderManager(); 
//instead do this:
myFragmentActivity.getSupportLoaderManager();
```

ó

```
//don't do this:
android.app.FragmentManager fm = myFragmentActivity.getSupportFragmentManager();
//instead do this:
android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager fm = myFragmentActivity.getSupportFragmentManager()
```

También es útil saber que mientras que un fragment tiene que ser incrustado en una `Activity` no tiene que ser parte del layout `Activity`. Se puede utilizar como un trabajador invisible para la actividad, sin UI propia.

Comment: Esta muy bien la respuesta traducida. Sin embargo, no sé si es conveniente que "copiemos" las respuestas que hay allí aquí. Si no, simplemente consistiría en traducir un sitio en el otro. Creo que el punto está en dar respuestas nuevas y en español. Realmente la mayoría de preguntas que se van a hacer aquí ya se han preguntado antes y es muy raro que haya preguntas que no se hayan hecho nunca.

Comment: @Error404 para este tipo de preguntas que son sobre conceptos no veo que esté mal traducirlo, ni quiero quitarle el mérito al que respondió(de hecho pongo la fuente). Este tipo de preguntas en StackOverflow en inglés al llevar más tiempo  han llegado a una respuesta que ha sido aceptada por un gran número de usuarios y en la que explican detalladamente la respuesta.

Comment: @Error404 -  Este tema ya se ha tratado en [Meta](http://meta.es.stackoverflow.com/q/14/6491) y esta dando saber de donde es...

Comment: Gracias @aldanux yo sólo la estaba traduciendo por si la persona que preguntaba no entendía muy bien el inglés y además la respuesta tenia bastante aceptación en el foro en inglés

Comment: @aldanux No había visto ese hilo de meta en realidad. Y tienes razón Joacer, igual para conceptos esta mejor adaptar una pregunta que ya está bien revisada por la comunidad que crear una nueva. Es simplemente una manía de que no me gusta copiar de otros sitios (no es una crítica porque lo hayas hecho Joacer, es una manía personal). Realmente la finalidad al fin y al cabo es tener un contenido bueno y de calidad :)

Comment: Aunque también es verdad y me hace gracia que nos basemos antes en las respuestas de Stackoverflow que en las propias documentaciones oficiales de las distintas plataformas.